# Dojo xhr get not setting XmlHttpRequest

Tags: php, ajax, dojo

I'm using Dojo 1.7.2 and I try the following code

```
var request = xhr.get({
        url: location,
        content : content,
        load : function( data ){
            for( var x in data )
                {
                    alert ( x + data[x] );
                }
        },
        error : function()
        {
            alert( 'Had an eror' );
        },
        handleAs : 'json'
    });
```

Then in php i do the following to try and detect the xmlhttprequest

```
function isAjax(){

    $ajax = (isset( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' ] ) ) &&
        ( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' ] ) ==  'xmlhttprequest' );

    return $ajax;
}
```

But the isAjax function returns false.

If I do `xhr.post` then it works fine. I'm thinking this is just a side effect of using GET instead of POST? Is that it or is it something else that I'm not checking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a standard that this header is appended - as it is an unnescesary overhead in most cases.

You need to set the header yourself - and can call it whatever you please really. What you want is `headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" }`:

```
var request = xhr.get({
    url: location,
    content : content,
    headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" }, // << < add this
    load : function( data ){
        for( var x in data )
            {
                alert ( x + data[x] );
            }
    },
    error : function()
    {
        alert( 'Had an eror' );
    },
    handleAs : 'json'
});
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't had a chance to test this but it looks very promising and quite obvious now that you mention it. However, why is it included in a post request then but not in a GET request?

Comment: Worked out well. I used the function provided below to do a more thorough ajax test too.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on Zend Framework version.

```php
function isAjax() {
    $header = 'X_REQUESTED_WITH';

    // Try to get it from the $_SERVER array first
    $temp = 'HTTP_' . strtoupper(str_replace('-', '_', $header));
    if (isset($_SERVER[$temp])) {
        return $_SERVER[$temp] == 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }

    // This seems to be the only way to get the Authorization header on
    // Apache
    if (function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        if (isset($headers[$header])) {
            return $headers[$header]  == 'XMLHttpRequest';
        }
        $header = strtolower($header);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            if (strtolower($key) == $header) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it should be <code>$header = 'X-REQUESTED-WITH'</code> up at the top. Other than that it worked very well.